# Dynamically binding lists with Spring's form tag

Tags: java, spring, dynamic-binding

I have a command object `FaxForm` and it holds a list of `FaxStatus` objects inside a `faxStatusList` property.

```
public class FaxForm {
  private List<FaxStatus> faxStatusList;
  public void setFaxStatusList(List<FaxStatus> faxStatusList) {
    this.faxStatusList = faxStatusList;
  }
  public List<FaxStatus> getFaxStatusList() {
    return faxStatusList;
  }
}
```

I initially had a JSP page that would bind the objects by performing the following:

```
<c:forEach items="${esaFaxForm.faxStatusList}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
  <tr class="tableAltBackground">
    <td>
      <form:checkbox path="faxStatusList[${loop.index}].selected"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form:select path="faxStatusList[${loop.index}].status" items="${esaFaxForm.statusOptions}" onchange="checkThisBox(this);"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="${statusContUrl}?id=${item.id}&status=${item.status}" onclick="openFaxWindow('${viewFaxUrl}?id=${item.id}', ${loop.index});">${item.name}</a>
      <form:hidden path="faxStatusList[${loop.index}].name"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="${statusContUrl}?id=${item.id}&status=${item.status}" onclick="openFaxWindow('${viewFaxUrl}?id=${item.id}', ${loop.index});">${item.id}</a>
      <form:hidden path="faxStatusList[${loop.index}].id"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

However, I am trying to figure out how I could do the binding without the forEach loop and index.  The examples on the [Spring](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html) website show the binding by setting the path to the list name.  Is there a way to bind the properties?  I've tried this but it fails:

```
<form:checkbox path="faxStatusList.faxStatus.selected"/>
<form:select path="faxStatusList.faxStatus.status" items="${esaFaxForm.statusOptions}"/>
```

The faxStatusList has a getter and setter method and the FaxStatus variables each have getter/setter properties.  I get the error "Invalid property 'faxStatusList.faxStatus' of bean class..."

Comment: faxStatusList is a indexed property. So you can not use something like faxStatusList.faxStatus. Use faxStatusList[<CURRENT_INDEX>].faxStatus instead.

Comment: I actually like your current code as an answer, as it offers a great deal of flexibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring form tags has a **checkboxes** tag. You can use it as follows to do the binding automatically:

```
<form:checkboxes items="${faxStatusList}" path="faxStatusList" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" delimiter="<br/>" onclick="yourOnClickMethodIfYouNeed(this);"/>
```

The above snippet will display a list of checkbox items delimited with the br tag. Any changes made to the state of the checkboxes will be reflected appropriately in your FaxForm. faxStatusList object.