# How to render <form:checkboxes> in page direction instead of line direction?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-webflow, jspx

I need to bind `Map<Long, String>` to checkboxes in a form.

Here is my code:

```html
<form:form modelAttribute="flowForm" action="${flowExecutionUrl}">
  <table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">Select A Group Please !</td>
    </tr>
    <td>
      <form:checkboxes items="${selectableQuestionarieGroups}" path="id" />
    </td>
```

It is working nice:

[image]

However, I need a newline after each checkbox, how can I achieve this?

Comment: use attribute `delimiter="<br/>"` as answered [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1934129/dynamically-binding-lists-with-springs-form-tag/1941857#1941857) . To have more control on the styling use cssClass or cssStyle attibutes (view the html source, before using them)